# Angular: Is it possibe to make a component that looks the same on the fron-end side reusable when needing to do different service calls?

Tags: angular

I currently have a component that has a few input fields and on blur a service call is done. The same looking component occurs a few times in my application but depending on where it is used it needs to do a different service call. Currently I have created 3 different components that look the same on the front-end side but do different calls. The problem with this is if I change the look I have to do it in three different components which will become harder to manage as the application grows. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a EventEmitter to catch the blur event

Declare the Emitter in your component and call it with the blur event :

```
@Output() action: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>()

ngOnInit() {
  fromEvent(document, 'blur').subscribe(() => action.emit())
}
```

Add the EventEmitter into the template of the parent component :

```
<child (action)="action()"></child>
```

Declare a function into the parent component and call whater service you need :

```
action() { // call service}
```